# What is the default encoding method for code assumed by Python interpreter?

Tags: python, encoding

Some people use the following to declare the encoding method for the text of their Python source code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Back in 2001, it is said the default encoding method that Python interpreter assumes is ASCII. I have dealt with strings using non-ASCII characters in my Python code, without declaring encoding method of my code, and I don't remember I have bumped into encoding error before. What is the default encoding for code assumed by Python interpreter now?

I am not sure if this is relevant. 
My OS is Ubuntu, and I am using the default Python interpreter, and gedit or emacs for editing.
Will the default encoding method by Python interpreter changes if the above changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Python 2 still uses ASCII as the default encoding. It only changed to UTF-8 with Python 3, and Arch Linux is the only distro where Python 3 is the default `python`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"I have dealt with strings using non-ASCII characters in my Python code, without declaring encoding method of my code, and I don't remember I have bumped into encoding error before"*? Unless you were working with Python 3, this is not possible, assuming you actually had non-ASCII characters *in your source code*.

Comment: @lukas: I remember I wrote a script that read a file with non-ASCII characters, and then output them to another file, without declaring any encoding method. All works

Comment: @Tim: That is something totally different. That's your program dealing with non-ASCII characters in strings, as part of processed data. But the source code encoding declaration affects what encoding your **source code** will be interpreted with - so it's only needed if you decide to directly put non-ASCII characters in your *source code*.

Comment: @Lukas: When my script read a file, doesn't the file content become a string? I also did some regex matching to modify the string, before writing it back to another file. What encoding method does Python interpreter interpret the string content?

Comment: @Tim updated my answer to show the difference.

Comment: @Tim: So, did my answer clear things up for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any explicit encoding declaration, the assumed encoding for your source code will be

- `ascii` for Python 2.x
- `utf-8` for Python 3.x

See [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and [Using source code encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding) for Python 2.x, and [PEP 3120](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/) for the new default of `utf-8` for Python 3.x.

So the default encoding assumened for source code will be directly dependent of the version of the Python interpreter, and it is **not configurable**.

---

Note that the source code encoding is something entirely different than dealing with non-ASCII characters as part of your data in strings.

There are two distinct cases where you may encounter non-ASCII characters:

- As part of your programs data, during runtime
- As part of your source code (and since you can't have non-ASCII characters in identifiers, that usually means hard coded string data in your source code or comments).

The source code encoding declaration affects what encoding your **source code** will be interpreted with - so it's only needed if you decide to directly put non-ASCII characters in your *source code*.

So, the following code will eventually have to deal with the fact that there might be non-ASCII characters in `data.txt`:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with `line`
```

But it **doesn't** contain any non-ASCII characters in the *source code*, therefore it doesn't need an encoding declaration at the top of the file. It will however need to properly decode `line` if it wants to turn it into `unicode`. Simply doing `unicode(line)` will use the system default encoding, which is `ascii` (different from the default source encoding, but happens to also be `ascii`). So to explicitely decode the string using `utf-8` you'd need to do `line.decode('utf-8')`.

---

This code however **does** contain non-ASCII characters directly in its source code:

```
TEST_DATA = 'Bär'    # <--- non-ASCII character on this line
print TEST_DATA
```

And it will fail with a `SyntaxError` similar to this, unless you declare an explicit source code encoding:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file foo.py on line 1, but no encoding declared;
see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

So assuming your text editor is configured to save files in `utf-8`, you'd need to put the line

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of the file for Python to interpret the *source code* correctly.

My advice however would be to generally avoid putting non-ASCII characters in your source code, exactly because if it depends on your and your co-workers editor and terminal settings wheter it will be written and read correctly.

Instead you can use escaped strings to safely enter non-ASCII characters in your code:

```
TEST_DATA = 'B\xc3\xa4r'
```

Comment: The byte literal ambiguity is fixed in Python 3: `b'ä'` (non-ASCII) now causes `SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.`

Comment: Python 2 documentation [states](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interpreter-and-its-environment): "By default, Python source files are treated as encoded in UTF-8." But as you said ASCII is the default on Python 2, so this is a documentation error.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Python source files are treated as encoded in UTF-8. In that encoding,  — although the standard library only uses ASCII characters for identifiers, a convention that any portable code should follow. To display all these characters properly, the editor must recognize that the file is UTF-8, and it must use a font that supports all the characters in the file.

It is also possible to specify a different encoding for source files. In order to do this, we put the below code on top of our code !

```
# -*- coding: encoding -*-
```

https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/interpreter.html

Comment: thanks. "By default, Python source files are treated as encoded in UTF-8." Is this treated by any/most standard Python interpreter?

Comment: What you state is only true for Python 3. For Python 2, which is still in wide-spread use, the default encoding assumed is ASCII.

Comment: @Tim about interpreters as Lukas says its for python 3 ! but the some of editors don't support UTF-8 !